# Original marker doee not go invisible when the route it's implemented

Tags: android

I added `polylines`to my map so I can trace routes between points. Right now, the `polylines` appear after pressing `Yes` in an `alert dialog`, that's activated when the user presses the `infoWindow`. So, my plan is to get the `marker` when it's clicked on the `Yes`, and when the polylines are traced, to hide it. I added `marker.setVisible(false)` but it does not hide the marker when the polylines are traced. It is weird that if I ask for the same routes again, the `marker` will now disappear. So on 2nd try it does indeed disappear, but not on 1st time.

The code:

```
 @Override
public void onInfoWindowClick(final Marker marker1) {
    if(marker1.getSnippet().equals("This is you")){
        marker1.hideInfoWindow();
    }
    else{
        final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setMessage("Doriți să mergeți la această alertă?")
                .setCancelable(true)
                .setPositiveButton("Da", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(@SuppressWarnings("unused") final DialogInterface dialog, @SuppressWarnings("unused") final int id) {
                        markerSelectat =marker1;
                        calculateDirections(marker1);
                        dialog.dismiss();
                    }
                })
                .setNegativeButton("Nu", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(final DialogInterface dialog, @SuppressWarnings("unused") final int id) {
                        dialog.cancel();
                    }
                });
        final AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
        alert.show();
    }
}
private void addPolylinesToMap(final DirectionsResult result){
    new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Log.d(TAG, "run: result routes: " + result.routes.length);
            if(mPolylinesData.size()>0){
                for(PolylineData polylineData: mPolylinesData){
                    polylineData.getPolyline().remove();
                }
                mPolylinesData.clear();
                mPolylinesData= new ArrayList<>();
            }
            for(DirectionsRoute route: result.routes){
                Log.d(TAG, "run: leg: " + route.legs[0].toString());
                List<com.google.maps.model.LatLng> decodedPath = PolylineEncoding.decode(route.overviewPolyline.getEncodedPath());

                List<LatLng> newDecodedPath = new ArrayList<>();

                // This loops through all the LatLng coordinates of ONE polyline.
                for(com.google.maps.model.LatLng latLng: decodedPath){


                    newDecodedPath.add(new LatLng(
                            latLng.lat,
                            latLng.lng
                    ));
                }
                Polyline polyline = mMap.addPolyline(new PolylineOptions().addAll(newDecodedPath));
                polyline.setColor(ContextCompat.getColor(Harta.this, R.color.scope_systems_gri));
                polyline.setClickable(true);
                mPolylinesData.add(new PolylineData(polyline, route.legs[0]));
                onPolylineClick(polyline);
                markerSelectat.setVisible(false);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: use marker.remove();

Comment: @milanpithadia I tried with this, but the outcome is the same

Comment: Debugging showed me that the `markerSelectat` gets the correct value, but the `.setVisible` or `.remove` does not work.

Comment: in witch line you put marker in map ?

Comment: The markers are added automatically when the map starts using `latitudes` and `longitudes` received from a server